# How to create the directory and store file in to it from assets folder?

Tags: android, file, sd-card, android-sdcard, android-assets

I am using below code to copy the file from assets to the Sdcard.

code:

```
  File file3 = new File("/sdcard/Alone.mp4");
    if(!(file3.exists())) {
        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        files.add("Alone.mp4");
        new myAsyncTask().execute(files);
    }

// AsyncTass for the Progress Dialog and to do Background Process
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, Void> {         
    ArrayList<String> files;         
    ProgressDialog dialog;         
    @Override         
    protected void onPreExecute() {             
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainScreenActivity.this, "Speech Tutor", "Loading...");         
    }         
    @Override         
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {              
        files = params[0];             
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {                 
            copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard(files.get(i));                
        }             return null;         
    }         
    @Override         
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {             
        dialog.dismiss();         
    }      
} 

    // Function to copy file from Assets to the SDCard
    public void copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard(String fileFromAssets){
        AssetManager is = this.getAssets();
        InputStream fis;
        try {

            fis = is.open(fileFromAssets);
            FileOutputStream fos;
//          if (!APP_FILE_PATH.exists()) {
//                APP_FILE_PATH.mkdirs();
//            }
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),fileFromAssets));
            byte[] b = new byte[8];
            int i;
            while ((i = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
                fos.write(b, 0, i);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now, with above code i am able to copy the file from assets to the sdcard. but instead of that i want is to store the copy file in to another directory available in sdcard.

So how to do it ??

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering: For what reason do you want to copy those files out of your APK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the file in some specific folder of sdcard, then following is the code.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folderName/"

And If you are looking forward to create a new folder, then following is the code.

```
String tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.foldername) + "/";
    prepareDirectory(); 


private boolean prepareDirectory(){
    try {
        if (makedirs()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", 1000).show();
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean makedirs(){
    File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
    if (!tempdir.exists())
        tempdir.mkdirs();

    if (tempdir.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files){
            if (!file.delete()){
            }
        }
    }
    return (tempdir.isDirectory());
}
```

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @anija: Actualy i need solution for my own code. but anyway i have solve it. Thanks.